# Variable binding for Informix returns an error

Tags: php, pdo, informix

I get the following error when I add :start as the parameter to skip. I know the SQL query works if I hard code the SKIP/NEXT values and the :customerID is left alone. If I remove the the :start clause and leave it as `SKIP 1 FIRST 5 ... WHERE t1.customer_num = :customerID ...` it works just fine. I cannot find why the the error is occurring.

The Error

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY004]: Invalid SQL data type: -11064 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]SQL data type out of range
```

Stuff I tried:

1. Using BindParam instead of BindValue to bind parameters by reference.
2. Using PDO_STR to try to bind :start as a string. No success.
3. Hard coding value for :start in the SQL query itself. This works.
4. Using `$sql->bindValue(':start', (int) 1, PDO:PARAM_INT);` — no go.
5. Trying number 4 by assigning to a PHP variable first, same result.

Any Suggestions? I am using PHP 5.3.(something recent) with Informix 11 using the PDO connector. Again, it works with customerID alone but not with :start and returns the above error.

```
$sql = null;
$sql= $conn->prepare('SELECT SKIP :start FIRST 5 TRIM(loc_esi_id) FROM customer       t1,customer_ts_data t2 WHERE t1.customer_num = :customerID AND t1.customer_num = t2.customer_num');

//Bind values to parameters(by value)
$sql->bindValue(':start',   $start ,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindValue(':customerID', $customerID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

//$sql->bindParam(':count',$count,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$results = null;
try{
$sql->execute();
$results = $sql->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
//Error Handling, etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the `:start` notation for a placeholder is neither standard SQL syntax nor (native) Informix syntax.  You need to use a `?` for the placeholder, thus:

```
$sql= $conn->prepare('SELECT SKIP ? FIRST 5 TRIM(loc_esi_id)
                        FROM customer t1
                        JOIN customer_ts_data t2 ON t1.customer_num = t2.customer_num
                       WHERE t1.customer_num = ? AND ');
```

(and if it all needs to be on one line in PHP, I apologize for massacring accuracy in the interests of readability).

Now, there is a chance that the PDO system converts the `:start` notation into `?` automatically, in which case we have a different problem.  But unless you're sure that the `:name` notation works, ...
One reason for not being sure is that the `bindValue()` call seems to need the names, rather than a number which the `?` is likely to need.  Did your code error check the `bindValue()` calls?

This ESQL/C code works, producing the output I expect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    $ char *dbase = "stores";
    $ int num_skip = 3;
    $ int num_fetch = 5;
    if (argc > 2)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [dbase]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    if (argc == 2)
    dbase = argv[1];

    exec sql whenever error stop;
    exec sql connect to :dbase;

    exec sql prepare p from "select skip ? first ? tabid, tabname from informix.systables";
    exec sql declare c cursor for p;

    exec sql open c using :num_skip, :num_fetch;
    while (sqlca.sqlcode == 0)
    {
    $ int4 tabid;
    $ varchar tabname[129];
    exec sql fetch c into :tabid, :tabname;
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
        break;
    printf("%d: %s\n", tabid, tabname);
    }
    exec sql close c;

    exec sql free c;
    exec sql free p;
    exec sql disconnect all;
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
4: systabauth
5: syscolauth
6: sysviews
7: sysusers
8: sysdepend
```

This shows that if the placeholder notations are used correctly, then you can use parameters for SKIP and FIRST.

If you can't find a way to get this to work with PDO, you may have gotten a bug.  If you can run your code with the environment variable `SQLIDEBUG=2:/tmp/your_sub_dir/check` set to some similar value, then you should find a record of what was sent to the server (apart from the connection setup) in a file with a name such as `/tmp/your_sub_dir/check_21484_0_aedc1e0`.  The number pattern is a little variable.  You can then run the `sqliprint` program on the file and see what PDO is sending to the server.  It will be a very quick way of determining whether PDO or Informix has a bug in it.

For example, part of the output I got from `sqliprint` was:

```
C->S (20)               Time: 2012-05-29 17:55:08.65225
    SQ_CONNECT
         "stores" [6]
         "stores" [6]

C->S (72)               Time: 2012-05-29 17:55:08.65239
    SQ_PREPARE
        # values: 2
        CMD.....: "select skip ? first ? tabid, tabname from informix.systables" [60]
    SQ_NDESCRIBE
    SQ_WANTDONE
    SQ_EOT
```

You can see the SQL statement sent very clearly.  If you don't see `?` placeholders, then there is a problem upstream; either the PDO driver for Informix is not doing its job properly, or it is being misused.  If you see the `?` placeholders, we would be into a different set of issues, but I that I'll be surprised if that's the problem.

The only caveat in the SQLIDEBUG mechanism is that you need to get the environment variable set in the environment of whichever process is connecting to the database.  For a standalone ESQL/C program, that's trivial.  If you're going through a web server and PHP, that may be trickier — but it can be done.

Comment: I forget to mention that I did try the position variant using ? instead of **:value**. **:value** is an alternative way that PHP handles parameters to avoid using position. I know for a fact **:value** works because if I hardcode the SKIP/FIRST values in and leave the other :value parameters intact, the query works as expected. I got around this problem by using the "dirty" method of treating the SQL like a string, using things like sprintf, etc to get the parameters into the statement and then preparing the resulting string.

Comment: Gruesome; it sounds a bit as if whatever code is parsing the request doesn't realize that SKIP and FIRST can be followed by placeholders, though that is surprising since it would be a lot harder to parse that way. Having said that, the `:name` notation is a confounded nuisance as it collides with the Informix native notations such as `dbase:owner.object`. Is that a placeholder or not? It also collides with `value::int` notation, though the double-colon can be used to disambiguate that. And also with `DATETIME(2012-05-30 15:30:29) YEAR TO SECOND`, at least in the variant where `:1` is OK.

Comment: Consider reporting the issue to the PDO team at IBM, if you can find the right email address (or URL).  'Tain't me, that's all, but you can tell 'em I sent you if they ask (jleffler at us dot ibm dot com).  It would be best if we had the SQLIDEBUG/sqliprint record of exactly what is being sent to the server (as well as what you sent to PDO Informix).

Comment: I just emailed the people responsible.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem -- prepared queried with SKIP/FIRST values as a parameter return "SQL data type out of range"

Comment: Yes. This was a bug in the PDO driver for Informix. I ended working around it by using string processing to build the raw SQL string and sending that as a parameter. The downside is the loss of string escaping, parameterization. Use with caution.