# PHP PDO parameter binding with UPPER and LOWER functions in Informix SQL WHERE condition does not work

Tags: php, sql, pdo, informix

**Works:**

```
$pdo = new PDO();
$string = 'TEST';
$search_string = $string . '%';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM companies WHERE name LIKE ? LIMIT 1';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$search_string]);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

**Doesn't work (difference being that `UPPER(name)` is used instead of `name`):**

```
$pdo = new PDO();
$string = 'TEST';
$search_string = $string . '%';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM companies WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE ? LIMIT 1';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute([$search_string]);
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

The error:

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY004]: Invalid SQL data type: -11064
> [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]SQL data type out of range.

**Works (injecting search string directly into the query):**

```
$pdo = new PDO();
$string = 'TEST';
$search_string = "'" . str_replace("'", "''", $string) . "%'";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE $search_string LIMIT 1";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

**Background information:**

- IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC14WE
- PHP version 7.2
- Column "name" data type lvarchar (-1), size 1024

**Questions:**

1. Any idea why the second example (using UPPER with parameter binding) is not working and how to resolve it?
2. Is the query from the third example (search string directly in query) safe from SQL injection? If not then what needs to be done?

Comment: FYI you can use `$pdo->quote($string . "%")` instead of using `str_replace()`. It's more robust.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803475/variable-binding-for-informix-returns-an-error for a similar problem. It was a bug in the Informix driver.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar. I guess it could indeed be a bug in the driver which means I'll have to use the query without parameter binding (at least for now). I originally tried using `$pdo->quote()`, but it's not working correctly. A string like `TEST'N` ends up as `'TEST\'N'`, which is wrong and breaks the query. Tried this and found some information [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/ids_esqlc_0015.htm). `str_replace()` seems to work well based on current tests, but not quite 100% sure it's good and safe enough.

Comment: Hmm, seems like another bug in the driver. That's the correct way to deal with a quote in MySQL, so they may have just copied the MySQL code, but it doesn't work for Informix.